# How to retrive the last inserted id using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

```
 SELECT event.event_name, restaurants.res_name 
 FROM event_choices
 INNER JOIN restaurants
 ON event_choices.res_id = restaurants.res_id
 INNER JOIN event
 ON event_choices.event_id = event.event_id
```

I am trying to get the last inserted records based on the `event_id` this query brings back all the records.

similar to what `mysql_insert_id()` would do.

Is it possible to modify the query to return only the last inserted record?

my data looks like this I need to return the last `event_id` and its matching `res_id`

```
event_id  | res_id
116       | 1
116       | 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT event.event_name, restaurants.res_name 
FROM event_choices
INNER JOIN restaurants ON event_choices.res_id = restaurants.res_id
INNER JOIN event ON event_choices.event_id = event.event_id 
WHERE event.event_id = (SELECT MAX(event_id) FROM event)
```

Comment: Buy using limit 1 gets the last row but i need to get the last inserted records based on the event_id

Comment: @Grundizer That is why we have both used an `order by` first to ensure the highest ID is at the top of the results, THEN we limit the query to only one result - ergo, the one you want.

Comment: Edited my answer...this won't limit the results to one and will grab the last `event_id`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear in my question, I have edited the question hopefully to make it a bit more clear, I need to return the results matching the event_id which are more than one

Comment: @AaronW. +1, and deleting my answer, you got this one in the bag :)